# Listview- filter Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've a `ListView` with multiple `TextView` in a single row. The `TextView` values are name, groupname, date and some hidden fields. And a spinner outside of this `ListView`. Once i select item from spinner `ListView` needs to filtered. That is the other row will be gone. I've try `setVisibility()` method but it's not works good. I'm using simple adapter. How can i achieve this. Please help me.

My piece of sample code:

```
    Spinner draft_filter = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.draft_filter);
     draft_filter.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {



                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Spinner draft_spinner = (Spinner) arg0;
                        String selected_string = (String) draft_spinner.getSelectedItem();
    //Save this String and filter the listview using this
    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
     ListView level1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    level1.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        for (int i=0; i<level1.getChildCount(); i++)
                        {
    // Set the Visibility of the row here
    }
                });

    //For loading listview
//Here fillmaps is the arraylist contains hashmap values
    String[] drafts = new String[] { "child_name", "age"};
    int[] controls = new int[] { R.id.item1, R.id.item2};
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), fillMaps,
                        R.layout.draft_observation_list_layout, drafts, controls);
                level1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How to filter this listview Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried lots of stuff but the solution is very simple:

```
((SimpleAdapter) MyActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(filter_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call adapter each time when Spinner item value is change with filtered list value.

Comment: I've achieve this using filter. Thanks for the help.